# How do I do the following update query with Informix database while outputting the updated value

Tags: sql, database, informix

How do I do the following query with Informix

```
UPDATE cars 
   SET c_no = c_no + 1
OUTPUT c_no
 WHERE c_id = 5006993
```

**Error**

> State:37000,Native:-201,Origin:[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, I have tried the query I have posted and searched online for ways to do this using Informix but didn't find anything that could be useful. This query works with MSSQL but not with Informix. In Informix it shows an error: A syntax error has occurred.
State:37000,Native:-201,Origin:[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix] (this is what I expected anyway)

Comment: Pretty sure there is no way to do that in just one statement. The OUTPUT clause is specific to SQLServer, Informix doesn't have anything like that. The closer one would be a calling a SPL which does the update and returns whatever value that you want it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get information back from an UPDATE statement like that in Informix.

You can find the detailed syntax of the Informix UPDATE statement at the IBM [Informix 12.10 Knowledge Centre](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0) — [UPDATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm).